# VScode sourceMaps detected but not used

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, source-maps

**Hi everyone !**

I'm using **VSCode** to work on an **OpenSource project in monorepo** with **lerna**, and I want to provide a package which contains the tools needed to contribute easily.

In order to do this in a way that seems pretty clean to me, I added my monorepo as a **submodule** in my workbench package.

Here is a **link to my current setup**: 
https://github.com/Aetherall/accounts-workbench

The main goal of this package is to give to the developper a working debugger configuration, which allows breakpoints and follows the Error stack **within the sources of the monorepo packages**.

I succeded to make VSCode read my sourcemaps.
Indeed, I switched on the trace options, and I saw in the logs that the .map files were resolved.

But, - and there is my issue - when I trigger an error, instead of leading me to the sources, **the debugger just show me the transpiled files**...

Here is a sample of my log for one file ( I can provide my whole log if needed to help me )

```
SourceMaps: sourcemap url parsed from end of generated content: 

AuthenticationServicePassword.js.map

SourceMaps.getMapForGeneratedPath: Finding SourceMap for 

/home/aetherall/Workspace/github/accounts/accounts-workbench/accounts/packages/Server/Authentication/Password/PasswordService/lib/AuthenticationServicePassword.js by URI: 

AuthenticationServicePassword.js.map

SourceMaps.loadSourceMapContents: Reading local sourcemap file from

/home/aetherall/Workspace/github/accounts/accounts-workbench/accounts/packages/Server/Authentication/Password/PasswordService/lib/AuthenticationServicePassword.js.map
```

here is my debugger config:

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Start dev server",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/config/start.js",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js",
            "${workspaceRoot}/**/lib/**/*.js",
            "!**/node_modules/**/*",
        ],
        "skipFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*", "<node_internals>/**/*.js"],
        "smartStep": true,
        "trace": "sm"
},
```

I am using **webpack** to bundle the workbench package (not the monorepo) and **tsc** to transpile the typescript packages in javascript with sourceMaps in my monorepo submodule

I can of course add more informations if needed

Thanks for helping me on this one !
I really can't get why sourceMaps arn't used by the debugger ...

If you do have a solution, please give me some explanations on the problem

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my issue :

Source Map loader for webpack

this way, the sourcemaps of the files imported and transpiled will be resolved within webpack.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader